# How to switch between intel and AMD graphics card?

Tags: ati, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, switchable-graphics

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 using a ZBook 14 which has Intel® Haswell Mobile graphics and an AMD FirePro M4100. Using the open-source radeon driver, how can I switch between the intel and the AMD card?

I'm using 14.04 so instructions for 13.10 and below don't apply.

Comment: and http://rudrageek.com/linux-now-supports-hybrid-graphics-systems-ubuntu-13-10/

Comment: I'm on 14.04. Those instructions are for 13.10.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics